# Configure Rexster to use Titan

Tags: titan, rexster

I'm trying to configure Rexster to use Titan by modifying the rexster.xml file in Rexster. 
But when I run

```
  http ://localhost:8182/graphs/mygraph
```

in my browser I get a message saying:

{"message":"Graph [mygraph] could not be found"}.

This is the part of the rexster.xml file I've modified:

```
    <graph>
    <graph-name>mygraph</graph-name>
    <graph-type>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graph-type>
        <graph-location>C:/titan-server-jre6-0.4.4/bin/mygraph</graph-location>
          <graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
              <properties>
                    <storage.backend>local</storage.backend>
                    <buffer-size>100</buffer-size>
              </properties>
              <extensions>
                <allows>
                  <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
                </allows>
              </extensions>
    </graph>
```

I've added all the jar files in Titans lib folder into Rexster under config/ext/titan and I've created a graph in Titan by using the gremlin shell i Titan:

```
    g = TitanFactory.open('mygraph');
    g.createKeyIndex('name', Vertex.class);
    v = g.addVertex(null);
    v.setProperty('name','x');
    v.setProperty('type','person');
    v.setProperty('age',20);
    v1 = g.addVertex(null);
    v1.setProperty('name','y');

    v1.setProperty('type','person');

    v1.setProperty('age',22);
    e = g.addEdge(null, v, v1, 'knows');
    e1 = g.addEdge(null, v1, v, 'knows');
    g.shutdown();
```

What am I missing?

[UPDATE]:

I had placed the jar files from Titan in the wrong directory in rexster, the are now in the right place in rexster. But when I now run the rexster server I get the following output:

```
    [INFO] Application - .:Welcome to Rexster:.
    [INFO] RexsterProperties - Using [C:\rexster-server-2.5.0\config\rexster.xml] as
    configuration source. 
    [INFO] Application - Rexster is watching [C:\rexster-server-2.5.0\config\rexster
    .xml] for change.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.thinkaurelius.tita 
    n.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration.configureGraphInstance(Lcom/tinkerpo
    p/rexster/config/GraphConfigurationContext;)Lcom/tinkerpop/blueprints/Graph;
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.getGraphFrom
    Configuration(GraphConfigurationContainer.java:124)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.config.GraphConfigurationContainer.<init>(Graph 
    ConfigurationContainer.java:54)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.reconfigure(XmlRex
    sterApplication.java:99)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.server.XmlRexsterApplication.<init>(XmlRexsterA
    pplication.java:47)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.<init>(Application.java:97)
    at com.tinkerpop.rexster.Application.main(Application.java:189)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What is the output in the console when you start Rexster Server?  It lists all the graphs as they are configured and should show something about that specific graph not being configured.

Comment: Had not looked at the output before, but it says [WARN] GraphConfigurationContainer - Could npt load graph mygraph. Please check the xml configuration. And it seem to be caused by that Rexster could not find the class com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I assume you are running on windows and using `rexster.bat`?

Comment: Yes I am, I've updated my question aswell, Noticed that I had placed my jar files in the wrong place in Rexster, but now I got a new error.

Comment: What version of Titan are you using?

Comment: I used 2.5.0 before, but I've now changed to version 2.4.0 and it is now working:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing the version of the rexster server, before I was using version 2.5.0. I am now using version 2.4.0 and version 0.4.4 of Titan.